# How to use sliding menu toggle() from fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

In my application I use Sherlock actionbar with sliding menu.

I can use the sliding menu toggle from Sherlock Fragment activity like this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        break;}
```

but now I am trying to hide the actionbar and want to use the actionBar menu button from fragments.

I hide the actionbar, but how can I use the toggle() from fragments?

Can anyone give me an idea how can I use android.R.id.home action from fragment instead of fragmentActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two way to done this:

1. In your Activity override onOptionsItemSelected and handle home button clicked and call super for other options menu. (new for home the toggle() will be called and other menu options you can handle them in the Fragment)

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
           toggle();
           return true;

       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```
2. define an interface in your `Fragment` and implements it on the `Activity`. Call the interface function on case `android.R.id.home` in the Fragment, then call `toggle()` in the `Activity`.

Comment: i want to use the toggle() from my fragment class not from my fragment activity class. isn't possible?

Comment: define a function in your activity getSlidingMenu() return the MenuDrawer, in the Fragment onCreate() call getActivity() and cast it to yor activity type. then call getSlidingMenu(); now you have the menuDrawer in your fragment

Comment: @JafarKhQ can you explain how an I do that: "define a function in your activity getSlidingMenu() return the MenuDrawer"